# Left Formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure how to use the left formula in this case. I got this sub that calls another sub and the result depend on what is in ws.cells(1, 2), but now I need a left formula because I can't check the whole cell. Any ideas?

```
Sub ForEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call BuscarImagemTavares(ws, ws.Cells(1, 2).Value)
    Next ws
End Sub
  Sub BuscarImagemTavares(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Produto As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    'Autor: Tavares

    If ws.Range("B2") = "ok" Then 'Verifica se celula B2 tem ok se sim não insere a imagem novamente
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ws.Range("B1") = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Imagem, CaminhoImagem As String

    If Len(Produto) = 3 Then 'acrescenta 00 antes do cod do produto
        Produto = "00" & Produto
    End If
    If Len(Produto) = 4 Then 'acrescenta 0 antes do cod do produto
        Produto = "0" & Produto
    End If

    Imagem = Dir("\\Clfssrvfar\ENGENHARIA\GESTAO_DE_PROJETOS\04. FOLLOWUP\09. ARQUIVOS PARA FERRAMENTAS\09.1 IMAGENS\09.1.2 IMAGENS PRODUTOS\" & Produto & "*", vbDirectory)

    CaminhoImagem = "\\Clfssrvfar\ENGENHARIA\GESTAO_DE_PROJETOS\04. FOLLOWUP\09. ARQUIVOS PARA FERRAMENTAS\09.1 IMAGENS\09.1.2 IMAGENS PRODUTOS\" & Imagem



    With ws.Pictures.Insert(CaminhoImagem) 'Mostra Imagem
        'Define tamanho e posição da imagem

    With .ShapeRange
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 115
        .Top = 7
        .Left = 715
    End With
    End With
    If CaminhoImagem <> "" Then 'Após inserir imagem informa "ok" na B2 para não inserir de novo
    ws.Range("B2").Value = "OK"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what does your `BuscarImagemTavares` sub does ? what kind of values are you trying to find in `ws.Cells(1, 2)` ?

Comment: What are you looking for? a particular string? Please be more specific.

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do here? Also can you post BuscarImagemTavares since we don't know what that does or what it's output is.

Comment: Just posted the other sub, the value can change so it's not an expecific string.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use left here and why? On Produto?

Comment: On Produto, basicaly produto code changes in every sheet and I want to insert its picture on that sheet. but the info on cell(1,2) is not the same in the directory of the image, thats why I need to use left, I only need the first 5 characters of the string.

Comment: Guys, I figured it out. I removed ".value" on Call and it worked. Dont ask me why but it did!!! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Call BuscarImagemTavares(ws, Left(ws.Cells(1, 2).Value, n))
```

Replace n with no. of characters you want from left.

Comment: I though that would work, but it didnt. I have no ideia what to do.

Comment: It worked, the code u gave me. I just had to remove ".value" - strange thing. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

```
Call BuscarImagemTavares(ws, Left$(ws.Cells(1, 2).Value, 4))
```

That will pass the first for characters of the cell. Change the 4 to whatever you want.

Comment: what is the exact value for `ws.Cells(1, 2).Value` ?

Comment: I did what sktneer said, its pretty similar, I just had to remove ".value" from it and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is you are looking for something like "If Cell (1,2) contains Herp do this"

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1,ws.Cells(1,2).Value,"Herp")>0 Then
        Call BuscarImagemTavares(ws, ws.Cells(1, 2).Value)
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Value in the cell will change for each ws, That was my first idea.

Comment: How does it change? What is your criteria?

Comment: There is no criteria, could be a number os letters, it's a srting and could be anything.